# Prove that the sequence $a_{n} = 1+\frac{1}{2n}$ converges to 1.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

This is what I have so far. Let $\varepsilon >0$.

We must show that there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies that $|(1+\frac{1}{2n} - 1| < \varepsilon$.

Since $a_{n} = 1+\frac{1}{2n}$, $∣1 + \frac{1}{2n} - 1∣ = \frac{1}{2n}$ and $\frac{1}{2n} < \varepsilon$ if $n > \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. According to the Archimedean  property, there exsts $n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\varepsilon} < n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2n_{\varepsilon}} < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Consequently, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds $n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n_{\varepsilon}} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2n} \leq \frac{1}{2n_{\varepsilon}} < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
thence we conclude the proposed result holds.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes

You look for $ N\in \Bbb N $ satisfying

$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N) \;\;\Bigl(n\ge N\implies n>\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\Bigr)$$

So, you can take
$$N=\lfloor \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\rfloor +100$$
You will be sure that
$$n\ge N\implies n>>\frac{1}{2\epsilon}$$
$$\implies 1+\frac{1}{2n}-1<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track. But you have yet to show what your $N$ is.

Depending on how the set of real numbers are introduced, you can either set $N$ to be $[\frac{1}{2\epsilon}]+1$ or apply the [Archimedean principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) to show that there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $N>\frac{1}{2\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

You got most of it. Now, you need to find an $N(\epsilon)\in \Bbb N$ which is bigger than the lower bound for $n$ (i.e. $\frac{1}{2\epsilon}$). In this case $N_\epsilon=\lceil\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\rceil$ satisfies.